# Magento 1: How can we use different Customer registration Page

Tags: magento-1.9, registration

I have multiple stores and i want to use different registration pages with some custom attributes is it possible we can use multiple registration page?

Comment: Yes, you will have to edit the template file which shows the registration page.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to implement this on website level  you can achieve it by going configuration on website level like:

**1)** go to `system->config.->design` , at your website level

**2)** create a new theme folder for your website in `app/design/frontend`

**3)** add exception theme for website and paste only your `register.phtml` file in that file other files will pickup from your regular theme.

I hope this might help.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply and i have done it earlier with same approach as you mentioned in addition i want to say i have not only add register.phtml file as well as i have done some in custom attributes on website thanks for your time.